# Easiest way to install mysqldump on Amazon Linux 2023 running on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-linux-2023

I need `mysqldump` (or `mariadb-dump`) inside my Lambda function.
I chose I want to go the Docker way and used the `public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20` base image.

To add MySQL/MariaDB I added the following to my Dockerfile

```
RUN dnf update -y && dnf install -y mariadb105-server
```

This works but bloats the image size to ~800MB.
Is there a better/easier way to only add `mysqldump` and the necessary dependencies?

I looked at the other services AWS offers but none really fit the bill ...

Dockerfile I'm testing with

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20

# Installing mysqldump and cleaning dnf cache
RUN dnf update -y && \
    dnf -y install mysql-utilities && \
    dnf clean all && \
    # dnf autoremove -y && \ # => not working b/c this is only microdnf which doesn't have autoremove
    rm -rf /var/cache/{dnf,yumdb,metadata}
```

Build command I use

```
docker build . --platform linux/amd64 -t mysqldump-node20
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the easiest but I think the lightweight solution is to bundle the mysqldump binary in your zip code source. Here were my steps:

- Spin up an EC2 with the correct [os based on your lambda runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html).
- Install mysql on the EC2. I used [this guide here](https://muleif.medium.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-amazon-linux-2023-5d39afa5bf11). Those steps consolidated are:

  - `sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el9-1.noarch.rpm`
  - `sudo dnf install mysql80-community-release-el9-1.noarch.rpm -y`
  - `sudo dnf install mysql-community-server -y`

    - If you get an error on that step about GPG keys you may also need to do `sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023` then rerun the last step.
- SCP `usr/bin/mysqldump` to your machine to zip with your code.

Then I just needed to make sure my code referenced it in the correct directory it ended up in based on folder structure of the zip.